# rootScope gets undifined when changing route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

So, when my user logs in I have this code

```
var promise = UserFactory.doLogin(userCredentials);

promise.success(function (data, status) { 

  //set some localstorage vars
  //only on login's success get additional data

   var anotherPromise = UserDataFactory.getUserData();                                   
    anotherPromise.success(function (data, status){                                      
           if(data.code == 2){                                                     
               $rootScope.userHead = true;
             }

});
```

`$rootScope.userHead = true;` will show/hide a sub-menu according to its value (true/false). The sub-menu's HTML is

`<div class="panel panel-default text-center" style="text-align: center;" ng-hide="userHeader">`

The page that includes the menu, is included in some pages with `<div id="submenu" ng-include="'submenu.html'" ></div>`. Those pages are in routes like so

```
            .when('/user', {                    
               templateUrl: 'user.html',                         
               controller: 'userController',
               animation: 'second',
               access: {
                    requiredLogin: true
                }
            }) 
           //user.html includes menu with ng-include="'submenu.html'"
```

When I go to the user page, the `$rootScope.userHead` has a value and the sub-menu is hidden as it should be. If I hit refresh, the `$rootScope.userHead` is `undifined` and I can see the submenu.

I dont see any overwrite to `$rootScope.userHead`. Does it looses its value when I go to another page? Shouldnt it keep its value?

What am I missing? How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: When you refresh the app restarts from zero. All services and variables instances are redefined. You just can't refresh a angular application and mantain non persistent variables.

Comment: @ItaloAyres Thank you. So, what do you suggest? Should I save the `userHead` elsewhere? Put it in local storage instead of Angular for example?

Comment: Maybe. But if when starting you app, you use an LoginService to see if the user is already logged, or something like that, you can set this config in that service. If you understand what I mean.

Comment: Root-scope resets on reset ,Cookies or local storage or session storage or Windows local storage  can serve the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you **reload** your page all information that you store in **JavaScript variables** are **lost**. `$rootScope` is nothing more then a variable in JavaScript. If you want to store something that persists a page reload there are at least the following possibilities:

- use a Cookie (in angular you could use the $cookieStore)
- use some of the new HTML5 features like Locale Storage, Web DB or the old DOM Storage (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage)
- store your data on a server
- ngStorage

Author: Micheal.